# Can the constructor be defined out of the class?

Tags: c++

Why gcc cannot compile successful of the codes below?
Can the constructor be defined out of the class?

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Person{
public:
    Person(const string &a, const string &b);
private:
    string name, address;
};

Person::Person(const string &a, const string &b){
    name(a);
    address(b);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Because neither `name` nor `address` are callable. You probably meant to put them into a member-initializer-list.

```
Person::Person(const string &a, const string &b)
    : name(a), address(b)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
Person::Person(const string &a, const string &b) : name(a), address(b) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just wrote it wrong. It should be:

```
Person::Person(const string &a, const string &b) :  name(a), address(b) { }
```

In principle, and very much in practice, too, you can and should define member functions outside the class definition to decouple the code base and reduce compile times.

Answer (score 2):

This is called separation of implementation and declaration. It is actually a good idea to keep your implementations separately, in a `cc` or `cpp` file.

Thus, in your header:

```
//Person.h
#ifndef PERSON_H  //  <---- include header guards in your headers
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
//using std::string; <--- you should remove this line, you don't want to import namespaces
//                        in your header file, or else they are imported in all 
//                        files including this header

class Person{
public:
    Person(const std::string &a, const std::string &b);
private:
    std::string name, address; // qualify your names in the header
};

#endif
```

and your implementation file:

```
//Person.cpp
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;  //  <---- if you wish, import the std namespace in your global namespace
                      //        in the implementation file
Person::Person(const string &a, const string &b):
    name(a),       // <---- correct syntax of initializer lists 
    address(b)
{
}
```